# Determine return type of generic function based on function parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a set of Typescript function that look like the following:

```
useMyHook = <T>(name: MyType) : T => {
    // do stuff here
}
```

The type of the parameter is a fixed set of strings:

```
type MyType = "foos" | "bars" | "bazs"
```

This all works fine, but it leaves some room for mistakes and it is more verbose than necessary because the parameter "name" and the Type "T" are directly connected and always need to match. If the name parameter is "foos" the generic type T is Foo, if the parameter is "bars" the type is Bar.

I could create separate strongly typed functions for each type, but the problem is that there is a large number of types and also several different functions. Without going to automatic code generation this would be very tedious.

As you might guess from the naming this is a custom hook for React, which adds another complication. My intial idea was to create a class to encapsulate the whole set of functions, but this doesn't really work well with how hooks are supposed to be used.

Type information is not available at runtime in Typescript, so I can't really determine the name parameter from the Type as that information is simply not there. But I was wondering if there is a way in Typescript to represent this kind of dependence between the string passed as parameter and the type of the generic function?

My goal is that I either have to only pass the parameter and the type is determined automatically. Is that possible with Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

This should be close, only thing that's missing is removing the `as any` at the end:

```
type Foo = { foo: number };
type Bar = { bar: number };

const useMyHook: (<Foo>(name: 'foo') => Foo) | (<Bar>(name: 'bar') => Bar) = (
  name: string,
) => {
  return (name === 'foo' ? { foo: 2 } : { bar: 3 }) as any;
};
```